# Visual Studio 2012 and Program Compatibility Assistant

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-7-x64

I have been successfully using VS2012 on Win7-x64 for months now. Today after restarting my machine launching VS2012 brings up this compatibility dialog:

[image]

Clicking "Check for solutions Online" has no effect.
I could run the program with "Run Program" but then VS2012 is not stable and I cannot run our custom development and source-control plugins.

Did anyone else ran into this issue with VS2012 or any ideas?
Appreciate your help.

Best,
Sarang

Comment: Great, it fixed my issue

Answer (score 37, accepted):

M$ realized they have problem with latest Windows updates and released the hotfix for VS2012.
For interested folks the hotfix is: Visual Studio 2012 hotfix KB2781514

Update:
As Carlton pointed: The hotfix is included in all Updates from 2 on
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301713

Comment: @EricLippert: that's good, however after paying $$$ and if my work grinds to halt I picture something else :)

Comment: Thanks for this, was searching for a fix then came across this!

Comment: Since time has passed, the best answer is now to install the latest Update (as in the other answer) - this hotfix is included in all Updates from 2 on. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301713

Answer (score 11):

Visual Studio 2012 hotfix KB2781514 (from Sarang's correct answer) is part of *Visual Studio 2012 Update 2*. Instead of installing just this one hotfix it is better to install [the latest update](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48708). As of this writing the latest one is Update 5.